# Python join method on a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'd like some clarification on the way the `str.join()` method works when passed a tuple.
Take for example this code snippet:

```
a = ("A", "B")
print(''.join(a))
```

This gives expected output: `AB`

So from this I ascertained that passing join an iterable (Such as a tuple) would allow it to unpack and "join" the contents together.

With this knowledge in mind I wrote the following generator expression:

```
import random
import string

generated_string = ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    generated_string = ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

I'm confused as to why this isn't working. I can manually iterate through the contents of the generator and "join" the tuples manually, for example:

```
generated_string = ((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4))

for val in generated_string:
    print(''.join(val))
```

Which gives the following output:

```
U7
W1
y7
G8
```

What am I missing here? It feels like it's obvious but I feel like I've covered all bases.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You added a loop in the second one

Comment: Your range-generator produces a iterable of tuples.

Comment: The one that fails tries to do a single `join`; the one that succeeds (as @wjandrea alludes to) `join`s each of the parts of `generated_string`.

Comment: @ScottHunter that makes sense. But doesn't a generator only yield one item at a time? In which case, a single tuple should be yielded to `join` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you pass an iterable to `join`, and the items must be strings. The iterable can be a tuple, generator, list, or whatever. However:

```
''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4))
```

That's not a tuple of strings, it's a sequence of tuples of strings.

```
print(list((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4)))
# [('w', '7'), ('X', '6'), ('W', '7'), ('P', '1')]
```

**Edit:** To fix it you can either nest two `''.join` like so:

```
''.join(''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits))) for _ in range(4))
```

or, since you know you're always joining exactly two items, use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
''.join(f'{random.choice(string.ascii_letters)}{random.choice(string.digits)}' for _ in range(4))
```

Comment: Great analysis.  Now how do you fix it?

Comment: @MarkRansom I fixed it with the following:  generated_string = ''.join(''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits))) for _ in range(4))

Comment: @the_slug I've edited my answer with a more elegant solution using f-strings.

Comment: @the_slug since there's only two strings being joined you don't even need to use `join`, a simple `+` will work fine.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you elaborate? I'm a bit confused as to where you're suggesting the '+' can go?

Comment: @the_slug `random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.digits)`

Comment: `+` works well here since both sides are strings, but f-strings have the advantage of converting their parts to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You pass generator of tuples to `join` method. But it can only take iterable object of `str`s. You can use function `map` which takes some function and iterable object and applies that function to every element of iterable object:

```
strings = list(map(''.join, ((random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.digits)) for _ in range(4))))
# strings = ['P9', 'b1', 'E7', 'z6']
```

And now you can join strings:

```
string = ''.join(strings) # 'P9b1E7z6'
```

Comment: But doesn't a generator only yield one item at a time? In which case, a single tuple should be passed to `join` ?

Comment: To get one item, you have to use `next` function. When you pass generator to other function, it can do with it whatever it wants and most built-in functions treat generator as iterable object